# document.getElementsByClassName('')[i].addEventListener('click', function() {};) EventListener only executes on the last element of the array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, checkbox

I am using Js to enable a form field when a checkbox is check otherwise its disable. I am using `document.getElementsByClassName` which returns an array of checkboxes then i add an `addEventListener` to each through a for loop. I then check if the box is checked and either `removeAttribute('diabled')` or `setAttribute` of a target form field which i get from the `href` of the checkbox. everything works great except that it only works for the element of the `getElementsByClassName` array.

html code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <form method="POST" action="/admin_accounts/editaccount.php">
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon input-group-addon-reponsive">
                <label for="memType">Member Type</label>
            </div>
            <select class="form-control" id="memTypeEdit" name="memTypeEdit" disabled>
                <option value="Regular">Regular</option>
                <option value="Ordinary">Ordinary</option>
                <option value="Associate">Associate</option>
                <option value="Executive">Executive</option>
                <option value="Honorary">Honorary</option>
                <option value="Dependant">Dependant</option>
                <option value="Instructor">Instructor</option>
                <option value="Volunteer">Volunteer</option>
            </select>
            <div class="input-group-addon"> 
                <input type="checkbox" class="edit-toggle" href="memTypeEdit"> 
                <label>Edit</label>
            </div>
        </div> 
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon input-group-addon-reponsive">
                <label for="employ">Employment</label>
            </div>
            <select class="form-control" id="employEdit" name="employEdit" disabled>
                <option value="None"              >None</option>
                <option value="President"         >President</option>
                <option value="Vice President"    >Vice President</option>
                <option value="Treasurer"         >Treasurer</option>
                <option value="Clerk"             >Clerk</option>
                <option value="Instructor"        >Instructor</option>
                <option value="Web Administrator" >Web Administrator</option>
                <option value=""                  >Volunteer</option>
            </select>
            <div class="input-group-addon"> 
                <input type="checkbox" class="edit-toggle" href="employEdit"> 
                <label>Edit</label>  
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
            <div class="input-group-addon input-group-addon-reponsive">
                <label for="regDate">Registration Date</label>
            </div>
            <input type="text" id="regDateEdit" name="regDateEdit" class="form-control" disabled>
            <div class="input-group-addon">
                <input type="checkbox" class="edit-toggle" href="regDateEdit"> 
                <label>Edit</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
            <div class="input-group-addon input-group-addon-reponsive">
                <label for="expDate">Expiry Date</label>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="expDateEdit" name="expDateEdit" disabled>
            <div class="input-group-addon">
                <input type="checkbox" class="edit-toggle" href="expDateEdit"> 
                <label>Edit</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon input-group-addon-reponsive">
                <label for="admin">Administrator</label>
            </div>
            <select class="form-control" id="adminEdit" name="adminEdit" disabled>
                <option value="0">Is Not Administrator</option>
                <option value="1">Is Administrator</option>                                        
            </select>
            <div class="input-group-addon"> 
                <input type="checkbox" class="edit-toggle" href="adminEdit"> 
                <label>Edit</label>
            </div>                                                        
        </div>
        <div class="text-right">
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" role="group">
                <button type="submit" name="create" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-info" value="Reset">Reset</button>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

and the Js:

```
<script>
    var anchors = document.getElementsByClassName('edit-toggle');
    for (var i = 0, length = anchors.length; i < length; i++) {
        var anchor = anchors[i];
        anchor.addEventListener('click', function() {
            var target = document.getElementById(anchor.getAttribute('href'));
            if (anchor.checked){
                target.removeAttribute('disabled');
            }else{
                target.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
        }, true);
    };
</script>
```

As it is right now the `name="adminEdit"` works as intended but non of the others but when I remove `class="edit-toggle"` from the adminEdit checkbox, the expDateEdit starts working. So it looks like on the last element works. any ideas? thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that in a loop, the value of `anchor` will end up being what it is when the last time the loop is run and all the event listeners will refer to the same anchor object. To solve this, you create a function which is executed immediately and you pass the `anchor[i]` to it to fix its value. Something like this should work.

```
<script>
    var anchors = document.getElementsByClassName('edit-toggle');
    for (var i = 0, length = anchors.length; i < length; i++) {            
        !function (anchor){
            anchor.addEventListener('click', function() {
                var target = document.getElementById(anchor.getAttribute('href'));
                if (anchor.checked){
                    target.removeAttribute('disabled');
                }else{
                    target.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
                }
            }, true);
        }(anchors[i]);
    };
</script>
```

As Squint points out, in this case, a simpler solution would be to just use `this` instead of `anchor`

```
<script>
    var anchors = document.getElementsByClassName('edit-toggle');
    for (var i = 0, length = anchors.length; i < length; i++) {
        var anchor = anchors[i];
        anchor.addEventListener('click', function() {
            var target = document.getElementById(this.getAttribute('href'));
            if (this.checked){
                target.removeAttribute('disabled');
            }else{
                target.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
        }, true);
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Worked great the only thing i had to do was name the function FireFox required the name

Comment: Yes. Two other solutions besides naming the function would be 1) putting an exclamation before the function: !function(){}(); or 2) wrapping the function in parenthesis: (function(){})(); I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @bradlystrachan: This is not the solution to use for your problem. All you need to do is replace `anchor` inside the event handler with `this`. While the solution is correct, that approach is very unnecessary here.

Comment: @squint - true enough. I will edit the answer to reflect this (no pun intended)..

Comment: ...also, as a side note, don't use `set/removeAttribute` for setting disabling/enabling. Use the `.disabled` property instead. The whole of your event handler can be reduced to this `document.getElementById(this.getAttribute('href')).disabled = !this.checked`. Though you should use `data-` attribute for non-standard attributes, like `href` on an `input`.

Comment: thank you @squint i will use that approach.

Comment: and thank you also @mseifert I learned alot from you answer I'm a beginner wit JS so your answer is not for not

Comment: Thank you again @squint very good feedback